Generic Email Function in a module to be used by different scripts with script specific Parameters, Subject and Body in Python
I have an email module and have two Functions defined that can be called by two different scripts .it works . But I was asked to write a single generic function that can be used by both the scripts.
My First function is
def email(en,fr,to,fcnt,fsize):


    fc=str(fcnt)

    fs=str(fsize)

    env=en

    from_email=fr

    receiver_email=to

    server=smtplib.Smtp('server')

    subject=f'Alert on {env}'

    text=f'discrepency in {fc} and{fs}'

    Message=f'subject{subject}\\n\\n{text}'

    Server.sendmail(from_email, receiver_email,message)

My second function is:
def email_rfb(en,fr,to,web_url, error_msg):


    env=en

    from_email=fr

    receiver_email=to

    Server=smtplib.smtp('server')

    Subject =f"Rfb alert on {env}"

    Url=str(web_url)
    error=str(error_msg)

    text=(url, error_msg)

    Message =f'subject{subject}\\n\\n{text}


Since I have some common variables I was asked to write a single generic function but my subject , text and positional parameters (fcnt,fsize, web_url and error_msg) are different . Can someone please help me in creating a generic function that would work in both the scripts when called

This is not a code writing service. If you show us how you've attempted to combine these two functions and explain where you're having trouble we would be happy to help out. Consider using optional keyword arguments for data that may only be required in some cases.

@larsks .sorry dint mean that . Thank you for the tip optional arguments

I understand I need use def(env,fr,to,*args) I have the issue in mapping fc and fs to the args . The script that calls this function has filesize =25Gb and file count =14 ( This changes as per the size and count). I need to pass these values to fs and fc
